# $.when(ajax1, ajax2, ajax3).always(ajax1,ajax2,ajax3) fires before the 3 requests are done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have 3 different services to ask for data. If the 3 are successfull, I can load my widget allright. If service1 and/or service2 are down or respond with error, I can still load my widget with limited features. If service3 is responding with error, no matter if service1 and 2 work ok, it means a total failure and I need to show an error message.

So I tried something like this:

```
var s1=$.ajax(url_service1);
var s2=$.ajax(url_service2);
var s3=$.ajax(url_service3);

$.when(s1,s2,s3).always(s1,s2,s3){
   //here the code that looks which services are ok or wrong 
   //to decide what to show and how;
}
```

But the $.when().always() code triggers as soon as one of the services responds with an error. The same happens with

```
$when(s1,s2,s3).then( successfunc, failurefunc)
```

meaning that as soon as the failure callback is triggered, due the failure of any of the 3 services, I can't check the status of the other 2.

So maybe I have a failure with service1 and I can't check if services2 and 3 are ok.

The only way to look for the 3 services to finish, no matter which is right or wrong I found so far is this:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
         console.log("finished");
});
```

But, I'm developing a small widget to insert in any pages. I would like it isolated from the rest of the content. So I don't want my widget to be waiting for the whole $(document) to solve al its ajax requests, if there are any...

Hope this makes some sense. I'm obviously a newbie about jquery ajax requests 
Thanks!

Comment: why not make a persistent class that notates the responses from all 3 ajax calls allowing you to make 3 different `$.when()` calls?

Answer (score 1):

This is all about catching errors (on service1 and service2) and recovering from them.

Promises make async error recovery very simple. In most promise libs, you would chain `.catch()`. jQuery doesn't yet have that method (roll-on jQuery v3!), however it's still very simple - chain `.then()` and return a resolved promise from its error handler.

Here's the flow control :

```
var s1 = $.ajax(url_service1).then(null, catch_);
var s2 = $.ajax(url_service2).then(null, catch_);
var s3 = $.ajax(url_service3);

$.when(s1, s2, s3).then(loadWidget, widgetFailure);
```

And here are some sample functions :

```
function catch_(error) {
    // Return a fulfilled promise that delivers a detectable error code, eg -1. 
    // Any value will do, as long as it can be distinguished from a successful value.
    return $.when(-1);
}

function loadWidget(val1, val2, val3) {
    //Exactly what you write here depends on how the widget is initialized when val1 and/or val2 are missing.
    // eg ...
    if(val1 != -1 && val2 === -1) {
        //load limited widget based on val1 and val3
    } else if(val1 === -1 && val2 != -1) {
        //load limited widget based on val2 and val3
    } else if(val1 === -1 && val2 === -1) {
        //load limited widget based on val3
    } else {
        //load full widget based on val1, val2 and val3 
    }
}

function widgetFailure(error) {
    $("#errorMessage").text('Sorry, widget failed to initialize') // show error message
    console.log(error); // log error
}
```

*Note: Due to the way `$.ajax()` delivers its data, successful val1/val2/val3 will be arrays each comprising [data, textStatus, jqXHR]. You will be interested in the data, val1[0]/val2[0]/val3[0].*

Thus, you should have exactly what you want :

- Total success if all three services succeed.
- Partial success if service1 and/or service2 fails.
- Total failure only if service3 fails, regardless of the outcome of service1/service2.

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bmt7216q/1/)**

Comment: Hum Roamer this is simply not working. It continues launching "widgetFailure" without ever getting to trigger "loadWidget"...

Comment: Then I would suspect that service3 fails every time. To help debug, add `console.log('catch', error)` to my `catch()` function, and chain `.then(null, function(error) { console.log('s3', error) })` to s3. Then run the code and look in your console.

Comment: No... I'm using mock services to test so I decide which fails. It never triggers loadWidget... Thanks anyway, I used iam-decoder comment and solved my problem so far.

Comment: Sandra, my bad, `catch` is a js reserved word and can't be used as a var/function name. Try changing `catch` to `catch_`;

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. That's not the problem. I changed the name to catch_something but anyway it works as the $.when().always(). As soon as one of the services fail, it triggers the failure callback. So I can't get the moment where the 3 requests are done, right or wrong. The only way to wait for the 3 services to finish so far is the one suggested by iam-decoder. Of course I can stop waiting for the other 2 services if s3 fails, but not otherwise.

Comment: @Sandra, my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bmt7216q/1/) proves to me that my suggestion works but maybe I have misunderstood the question. See if you can make a demo of what's not working for you.